# How to automatically resend iMessage when Internet is accessible?

Tags: iphone, messages

When using `Messages`, if I don't have an Internet access for some reason and the message does not send, I have to manually go back and resend any unsent message.

Is there any way to do this like `WhatsApp`, where it just waits until the Internet access is available and then sends without any user intervention?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you use `WhatsApp`? It is providing many other functions which make it much advanced than `Messages`.

Comment: I'm not really cool with all the WhatsApp/Facebook integration coming.

Comment: I share your concern: my trust in WhatsApp melt down since Facebook engulfed them. I am testing Signal for sensitive communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature does not exist on the iPhone.

You can provide feedback for the feature to be added [here.](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) For now, you will just have to live with it or use another app like WhatsApp.

> There is no such feature as yet on iPhone.

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250118315?answerId=250214213022#250214213022))

Comment: This isn’t quite correct: this isn’t a function missing from the iPhone, but just from `Messages`. `WhatsApp` provides it as rightly stated by @Evan.

Comment: @danielAzuelos that’s what I said